# Display long SLURM QoS names

Tags: slurm, qos

I am trying to find out a way to display long QoS names in SLURM (bigger than 9 characters). I have created a QoS with the following command

`sacctmgr add qos verylongname`

But when using `sacctmgr show qos format=name` i get the following:

```
$ sacctmgr show qos format=name
      Name
----------
verylongn+
```

As you can see the name is clipped after 9 characters. Is there a way to find out the full name of the SLURM QoS item?
For example, suppose you forget the long name but want to delete a QoS item, unless specifying it's full name the operation can't be done.

```
$ sacctmgr delete -i qos verylongn+
 Nothing deleted
$ sacctmgr delete -i qos verylongname
 Deleting QOS(s)...
  verylongname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` parameter accepts an optional argument specifying the width of the column:

```
sacctmgr show qos format=name%-40
```

The `%` sign indicates the width specifier, the `-` means "justify left" and `40` is the width in chars of the column.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Do you happen to have a link to documentation for such things?

Comment: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html#SECTION_GLOBAL-FORMAT-OPTION